# Cisco 1800 series router simulation program

Tags: cisco, router, ios

I need to know how to program these routers for school, but I need to exercise at home. Are there simulators for the console interface, for learning purposes? I took a look at eBay to get one, but they were quire out-of-budget ;-).

Thank you for your help!

Yvan

Comment: Does your school not give you access to a lab?

Comment: ofcourse, but not during the exam preparation week, in which I am atm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I highly recommend the GNS3 (graphical network simulation) tool. http://www.gns3.net

It's a collection of several applications that each do their own part to make things work.

- Dynamips, the core program that allows Cisco IOS emulation.
- Dynagen, a text-based front-end for Dynamips.
- Qemu, a generic and open source machine emulator and virtualizer.

The caveat here is that you need a copy of the IOS image you intend to run.  Suffice to say, you generally need a smartnet contract or CCNx login on Cisco site to obtain it. With a little searching though, you'll likely find it.

It's been a while since I fired up GNS3 so I can't say with 100% certainly that the 1800 model was supported.  However many routers are, and the functionality for command sets would likely be good enough if the 1800 isn't in there.

Comment: ISR (1800-2800-3800) are not and will not be supported by dynamips. http://gns3.net/hardware-emulated

Answer (score 1):

I used this in the past, and it is free. It does not specifically say the 1800, but it may suit your needs.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/practice-cisco-router-configuration-using-a-free-emulator/419

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about 1800-series routers, but [there is software that emulates a number of routers](http://www.ipflow.utc.fr/index.php/Cisco_7200_Simulator) - may be worth looking at.  [It even has front-end software that makes it less hideous to use](http://www.dynagen.org/).

Answer (score 1):

An 1841 series router is simulated in Cisco Packet Tracer version 5.1 which provides quite an adequate representation of IOS especially for training purposes up to CCNA level.

Comment: I can vouch for Packet Tracer aswell! Using it for simulating changes in a very large network. Worth a shot!